# How do i upload a vue.js website using IONOS?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ionos

I have made a personal website with vue and I needed to upload it online, I dont know why but I chose IONOS because google recommended it. Now I am strugglinmg to upload it as this seems very confusing. Does anyone know how to operate IONOS? I have tried to submit it using FTP and SFTP.

Comment: Does [www.ionos.co.uk/help/hosting/managing-webspace-with-webspaceexplorer/uploading-a-file-using-webspaceexplorer/](https://www.ionos.co.uk/help/hosting/managing-webspace-with-webspaceexplorer/uploading-a-file-using-webspaceexplorer/) help?

Answer (score 0):

IONOS is offering a tool that is named [Deploy Now](https://www.ionos.com/hosting/deploy-now) and you can find instructions for Vue.js [here](https://docs.ionos.space/docs/from-cmd-line/#vue-app)